# configure redux saga modular way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using create-react-app for my project. Now that i need redux-saga for async operation, I am facing an issue on configuring sagas in a modular way. By modular way, what i mean is, there will be one main sagas file which will export all the component's sagas. for example there are 5 components, component1, component2, component3, component4 and component5. Each component will have their own actions, reducers, constants and sagas. How can i configure such way?

I could do the following way but what is the best approach to handle such?

Here is my source code

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import rootSaga from "../app/sagas";

const configureStore = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  return {
    ...createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
    runsaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  };
};
```

**sagas.js**

```
import component1Saga from './component1/sagas';
import component2Saga from './component2/sagas';

export default function* appSaga() {
  yield [component1Saga, component2Saga];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, let's look at how [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) does it.

In their `configureStore` function, they call their sagas (https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/store.js#L18). You can use your saga extensions (if you have any) like https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/store.js#L42.

Now, you export your individual sagas like https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/sagas.js.

You can inject sagas in your routes like https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/routes.js#L26. But, before that, you will have to create some helper function which does that injecting for you like https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/utils/asyncInjectors.js#L77.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have just used that boilerplate yesterday and I am a fan of that boilerplate but the problem is i am using react-router v4 in another project that is why i am having problem with async saga injection.